# Some guidance on json structure to a django DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model structure like this:

```
model:
    server_name: str
    description: str
    owner: str
```

but the application sending data to my app use a json format I am not sure on how to create a serializer for. For multiple entries it looks like this

```
{
    "server1": {
        "description": "desc of server 1",
        "owner": "service name"    },
    "server2": {
        "description": "desc of server 2",
        "owner": "service name"
    }
}
```

but I am not sure on how to get it into something matching my model. This is the structure I would like it to have in the serializer

```
[
    {
        "server_name": "server1", 
        "description": "desc of server 1",
        "owner": "service name"
    },
    {
        "server_name": "server2", 
        "description": "desc of server 2",
        "owner": "service name"
    }
]
```

Any suggestions on this one?

Answer (score 0):

with the help of the Documentation [ListField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield), you can try this:

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ServerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    jsonData = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.JSONField()
    )
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import ServerSerializer

class ServerAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        # Get data
        json_data = data.get('jsonData')
        for item in json_data:
            server_name = item['server_name']
            description = item['description']
            owner = item['owner']
            YourModel.objects.get_or_create(
                    server_name=server_name, description=description, 
            owner=owner)
        result = YourModel.objects.all()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(result, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: On the serializer I get
```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `jsonData` on serializer `ServerSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Server` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Server' object has no attribute 'jsonData'.
```